# chowned /usr to myself, how to recover?

Tags: chown

I accidently ran `chown myname /usr -R` and now the login screen won't show up! I have tried various things in the root terminal, but nothing works. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

open tty1 <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>

Login with your username and password

Now

```
sudo chown root /usr
```

Return back to your GUI tty <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>

and try to login

Comment: Nothing happened, I think it should be -R, I tried with it, no luck.

Comment: Then you probably did something else. what is output of `ls -l /usr`